# how do i convert all the date and time in angular 6 application to the user's machine date and time format

Tags: angular, date

I wanted to convert all the date and time displayed in my application to user's machine date and time format. For e.g if user sets the date format as 'YY/MM/DD' then in application it should show date in 'YY/MM/DD' format for that user. Similarly if other user sets as 'MM/DD/YYY' then it should show 'MM/DD/YYY' format. How to get the date and time format of the user's machine?

I tried with .toLocaleString(), it did't worked in some versions of edge browser and also in chrome.

Comment: What function are you using to format your date to string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

> new Date().toLocaleDateString()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a datepipe:

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
const convertDate = datePipe.transform(new Date(date),  'yy/MM/dd');
```